# Category Theory: Object to Function Link Notation

Tags: functions, notation, category-theory

Let `f:a→b` in the category of sets. Let `f'` be an object in the category of sets, which represents the homset containing only `f`.

Given that `f` and `f'` represent the same thing (just at different levels of abstraction), is there some standard notation which is used to explicitly link `f` to `f'` (and visa versa) in category theory?

[image]

Comment: It's possible but not typical that $\mathsf{Hom}(a,b)=\{f\}$. At any rate, you can use the cartesian closure of $\mathbf{Set}$ to turn an arrow $1\to\mathsf{Hom}(a,b)$ into an arrow $a\to b$. This is essentially [uncurrying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) (combined with simplifying $1\times a$ to $a$). This does not depend on $\mathsf{Hom}(a,b)$ being a singleton set.

Comment: @DerekElkins So, there is no scenario (and hence no notation) for directly linking an object (for lack of better terms, 1-cat objects) to a function (2-cat objects)? I come from an engineering background, so when I look at diagrams such as in category theory I first ask "what else can I do". If its not possible, that is also fine. =) If you leave it as an answer then I'll mark it as correct.